# Вывод результатов 2 запросов в временную таблицу MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

Здраствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в коде языка python реализовать такую конструкцию: нужно выполнить 2 запроса в базу mysql и вывести результаты в временную таблицу.

Answer (score 3):

Запросы хоть совместимы по выводу? по числу и типу полей? Зависят друг от друга? Что значит «временная» таблица? Должна ли удаляться после рестарта? Поместится ли в память? Что предполагается с ней делать дальше? Нужно всё это проделать только один раз или же несколько?

Вариантов тут много. Например:

```
CREATE TABLE test ENGINE = MEMORY
    SELECT *
      FROM table
      WHERE something = 'foo'
    UNION
    SELECT *
      FROM table
      WHERE something = 'bar';
```

Может, вам лучше [view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) сделать. Может, в CSV выгрузить. Ничего ж детально не сказали.

Comment: задача состоит в том чтобы обьеденить в какуюто временну таблицу результаты.. есть 2 несвязаные таблицы в одной есть список ip адресов в другой имя хоста, мне необходимо их обьеденить что бы результат запросы выводил их в такой конструкции:
ip - host
также неообходимо чтобы данные обновлялись какждый раз когда будут запускать скрипт..